# Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'keras_preprocessing.sequence.TimeseriesGenerator'>, <class 'NoneType'>

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I got this error:

```
model.fit(generator,epochs=50)

ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'keras_preprocessing.sequence.TimeseriesGenerator'>, <class 'NoneType'>
```

When i define model like this:

```
n_input = 12
n_freatures = 1
generator = TimeseriesGenerator(scaled_train, scaled_train, length=n_input, batch_size=1)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu', input_shape= (n_input, n_freatures)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
```

I've tried install tensorflow 2.4.0 & keras 2.4.3

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.4.0
!pip install keras==2.4.3
```

but not working

My generator looks like this:

```
X,y = generator[0]
print(f'Given the Array: \n{X.flatten()}')
print(f'Predict this y: \n {y}')

Given the Array: 
[0.14470019 0.16253949 0.15644509]
Predict this y: 
 [[0.16692908]]
```

Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: Try the workaround mentioned on similar thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65207373/keras-model-fit-valueerror-failed-to-find-data-adapter-that-can-handle-input